# Master-Detail using Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, master-detail

Then I have my `MasterViewController` with its `DetailViewController` segued both.

I'm using Parse for backend platform, and I have a little problem for this: How to pass displaying datas of the `MasterViewController` to the `DetailViewController`

I'm using a `NSArray` called `"RetrievingObjects"` to retrieve it, For my Parse class querying it works successfully (I already used my query and my `Array` to display cells in `MasterViewController`), I use that method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailViewController *detailVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"];

    detailVC.lblDescription = [self.RetrievingObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailVC.lblTitleForDescr.text = [self.RetrievingObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailVC.dateForDescr.text = [self.RetrievingObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToDetailSg" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually using `detailVc` anywhere. You should set it up in `MasterViewController`'s `prepareForSegue:sender:` You can access what will become the `DetailViewController` through the segue object's `destinationViewController` property and set everything you need there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the detail controller in code.  If you have your segue set up correctly in the storyboard, that work will be done for you.

Instead, implement `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`, get the detail controller from the segue parameter, and pass the information you want it to display in that method.

Note that the destination controller's view will not have loaded at that point, so don't try to update `IBOutlet`s.